# Implementing `components(separatedBy:)` method in Swift

Tags: algorithm, swift, complexity

On looking at the `components(separatedBy separator: String) -> [String]` method from the **Swift Standard Library**, I tried to come up with an implementation just for practice. Your comments are welcome to improve the same. Thanks.

---

**Input:**

```
func main() {
    let sampleString = "Do not be sorry. Be better."
    print(sampleString.components(separatedBy: "."))
}
```

**Output:**

```
["Do not be sorry", " Be better", ""]
```

**Implementation:**

```
extension StringProtocol {

    func components<T>(separatedBy separatorString: T) -> [String] where T: StringProtocol {

        var currentIndex = 0; var stringBuffer = ""; var separatedStrings:[String] = []

        forEach { (character) in

            if String(character) == separatorString {
                separatedStrings.append(stringBuffer); stringBuffer = ""
            } else {
                stringBuffer += .init(character)
            }

            if currentIndex == lastIndex { separatedStrings.append(stringBuffer) }
            currentIndex += 1
        }
        return separatedStrings
    }
}

extension Collection {
    var lastIndex:Int {
        get {
            return self.count - 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please point to the SL implementation of `components(separatedBy separator: String) -> [String]`?

Comment: @Carpsen90 Sorry I am not able to find it. I just tried to implement out of my own interest.

Comment: @Carpsen90 - It’s found in `swift-corelibs-foundation`: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/6119b3328d65644b0af16baf04ae9ce58559f6bb/Foundation/NSString.swift#L987. When looking for stuff like this, go to the repo in question and then search for ["func components"](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/search?q=%22func+components%22&unscoped_q=%22func+components%22) (with the quotes).

Comment: Martin has answered your questions. But let’s assume for a second that you really did want to advance `currentIndex` yourself. I would not make it an `Int`. I’d also eliminate that `lastIndex` property. Instead, define `startIndex` as `var currentIndex = startIndex`, advance it with `currentIndex = index(after: currentIndex)` and then check if I’m at the end with `if currentIndex == endIndex { ... }`. It’s all moot, as this should be refactored out, as Martin points out, but just a few observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Coding style

This is of course a matter of personal taste, but would split multiple statements like

> ```
> var currentIndex = 0; var stringBuffer = ""; var separatedStrings:[String] = []
> ```

into separate lines

```
var currentIndex = 0
var stringBuffer = ""
var separatedStrings:[String] = []
```

I would also start new lines for nested code blocks, i.e.

> ```
> if currentIndex == lastIndex { separatedStrings.append(stringBuffer) }
> ```

becomes

```
if currentIndex == lastIndex {
    separatedStrings.append(stringBuffer)
}
```

#### Correctness

Your function takes a separator of type *string (protocol)* as an argument, but actually works only for separators consisting of a single character. Example:

```
let sampleString = "Do not be sorry. Be better."
print(sampleString.components(separatedBy: ". "))
// ["Do not be sorry. Be better."]
```

The reason is that here

> ```
> if String(character) == separatorString
> ```

a single character of the source string is compared with the separator.

Your method also behaves differently from the standard library version when called with an empty string,

```
"".components(separatedBy: ".")
```

returns an empty array `[]` instead of a single-element array `[""]`. The reason is that the check

> ```
> if currentIndex == lastIndex { separatedStrings.append(stringBuffer) }
> ```

is never done for an empty input string. (Checking for the last iteration *inside* a loop always makes me suspicious.)

#### Simplifications

Instead of converting a character to a string for appending

> ```
> stringBuffer += .init(character)
> ```

you can append it directly:

```
stringBuffer.append(character)
```

Keeping track of the current character position can be done with
`enumerated()`

```
for (currentIndex, character) in self.enumerated() {
    // ...
}
```

instead of incrementing `var currentIndex`.

#### Efficiency

The main bottleneck is the

```
var lastIndex:Int
```

extension method. For Strings (and other collections which are not random accessible) determining `self.count` is a O(N) operation (N = number of characters). It requires traversing the entire string.

This method is called for each character in the source string, so that this contributes O(N^2) to the execution time.

It would also be more efficient to locate the next occurrence of the separator and append an entire substring to the result array, instead of appending single characters repeatedly.

#### Alternative implementation

Here is an alternative implementation, considering the above suggestions:

```
func components<T>(separatedBy separatorString: T) -> [String]
    where T: StringProtocol, Index == String.Index {
        var separatedStrings: [String] = []
        var pos = startIndex
        while let range = self[pos...].range(of: separatorString) {
            separatedStrings.append(String(self[pos..<range.lowerBound]))
            pos = range.upperBound
        }
        separatedStrings.append(String(self[pos...]))
        return separatedStrings
}
```

Comment: @Carpsen90: I doubt it. I *assume* that the subscript transforms `pos...` to `pos..<endIndex` using [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Range.swift#L582) method, so there should be no difference. – See also https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0172-one-sided-ranges.md#detailed-design.

Comment: Thanks. I had a faint doubt that *that* transformation would cost some extra work, either at compile or run times.

Comment: Thank you so much for your review, @MartinR! 